# django-dajaxice seems don't work

Tags: python, django

I use [django-dajaxice/dajax](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) for ajax operation of Django. But after referring several topics about configuration:
   
   http://simonsstuffandthings.blogspot.com/2012/05/installation-and-use-of-dajax-and.html
   http://www.pythondiary.com/tutorials/django-and-ajax-dajax.html

I still couldn't configure it correct. I think the problem comes from the call "Dajaxice.myprojectname.myappname.functionname" because I don't understand the theme in this call (it needs to def function in axis.py in myappname), could anybody explain that? Thanks~

And when I download [django-dajaxice-0.2](https://github.com/jorgebastida/django-dajaxice/downloads), I try to run example in examples while it seems not work.
   Could anyone give me some advice to configure dajaxice? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin here, the author of the Python Diary article you posted up there.  Firstly, thank you for the mention.

Dajaxice and Dajax can be somewhat tricky to set-up on older versions of Django, however the newer versions of Django and Dajaxice are much easier.  It appears that you are not using the most recent Dajaxice version, which is django-dajaxice==0.5.5, your first goal should be to upgrade that package.

If you need some example settings.py, and urls.py files, check out my template for this on my website:
http://www.pythondiary.com/templates/djangodevelopment

This is a project that I am currently using for all new Django 1.5 projects, and it comes with a handful of helpful tools to get anybody started from newbies to vets alike.